# Android: Building davfs

Tags: android, webdav, fuse

I'm trying to build the davfs fuse module for android, and I'm not exactly sure how far I need to go here. I'm not looking to build an app (though maybe I need to), just build the module so that I can use it from Tasker.

Do I need to go the whole nine yards and replicate the entire environment on my device from source, or is there a shorter route?

Comment: Are you doing this for rooted device? Cause afaik you can't have fuse filesystems on "regular" android without rooting it.

Comment: How did it go? I was looking for something like that! :)